# Let G be a group. Prove that the function: $G→G, x→x^2$ is a group homomorphism if and only if G is an abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let G be a group. Prove that the function: $G→G, x→x^2$ is a group  homomorphism if and only if G is an abelian group.

Is this the same as if $f:G→G$ is defined by $f(x) = x^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, you have to consider the function $f:G\rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x):=x^2$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying ! @JoseBrox